# Is my microservices architecture in line with best practises? (STS/SPA/Frontend API/Backend services)

Tags: architecture, signalr, microservices, identityserver4

Goal is to make an application with a SPA frontend that updates realtime, incorporating microservices architecture.

I have
- An SPA (Angular)
- A frontend API (for the SPA) which exposes api and signalr hub
- Some backend services 
- Azure Servicebus for operations on backend and notification for front end api that something is updated (in which case a signal R message gets pushed)
- Identityserver 4.0 as STS (and asp.net core identity as store)

Im struggling on making a good safe scalable architecture of my system. 
I dont want unneccesary overhead nor want to create a big monolith. I want the backend services to be hidden from the rest of the internet but the frontend Api can access it.

I want the frontend API to be intelligent enough to query for specific needs that the SPA needs and to listen to events relevant for the SPA to get notified off via SignalR. In other words: i dont want a dumb gateway.

Feel free to school me. I just want to get started with implementation.

I feel the lines from backend to STS is overkill if I only allow access from the frontend API.

I really need some insight.

This is what I made thusfar:
[image]

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Pls leave a comment

Comment: According to the two close votes this question is too broad.

Comment: I realised too late that this is not the right place to post these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1):

We are implementing a microservice architecture, and we use a [ReverseProxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) to terminate the public requests and to forward calls on to internal services.

Inside this proxy is all the code for calling out to Identity Server. I don't think that you want to do this from your backend services.

You may want to add some kind of session management service, which creates an identifier that you can then pass into all of your service calls.

You may also want to consider using Docker to host your services to ensure that they are isolated and consistent across environments, and an orchestration tool like Kubernetes to manage the containers.

Comment: Thanks alot. I decided making my Proxy for my client and im gonna include SignalR connections to that Proxy from that Proxy to the client. Not gonna alow SignalR connections into the backend. In order to push SignalR messages the Proxy will subscribe to certain events and push the results via Signal R to the client. I will use Docker and Kubernetes in the future, first I would like to setup my main business logic and have a working system for a POC.